# How to convert a nested List<object> to nested object[] array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, nested-class

How do I build a single function with which I can convert a nested List to a nested object[] array effectively?

p.s. the depth of the nested List varies.

for example:

```
public class ProductBindingViewSC
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string aName { get; set; }
    public List<Product_SuperType_Info> SuperTypeList { get; set; }
    public List<Product_Image_Info> Product_ImageList { get; set; }
    public List<Product_Property_BindingViewSC> Property1 { get; set; }

}
```

Property1 has structure like ProductBindingViewSC ( it has fields and List)

I need to do the following with only a few lines

```
List<ProductBindingViewSC> productList =  new GetProductObject().getProductBySomeCondition( 123 );
var productArray = SomeFunction(productList );
```

or

```
ProductBindingViewSC product =  new GetProductObject().getProductById( 345 );
var product = SomeFunction(product );
```

**ProductArray** has the exact same structure as **ProductBindingViewSC** but all the **List** Type are **Array** Type instead.
And if one of the object in **List** is empty, the array class will have one record of empty object in the **Array** .

EDIT:
Question : how should I write the  **SomeFunction**. I can only think of looping with very ineffecient way and mine is not generic. I need a function which I can throw in any object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnally, I'd just manually write a function that converts a ProductBindingViewSC into a ProductArray member by member, and then use List.ToArray()+Array.ConvertAll() or Linq's .Select().ToArray().

You could also use reflection, even make that not *too* slow thanks to open property delegates and generic type instantiation (in short, *anything* to avoid a sluggish GetValue()), to automatically convert from one type to the other, but that's quite a long story to explain.

- It involves first writing a generic interface `ICopyMember<TIn, TOut>` to expose a copy method but not the type of the members. Then implement this interface in a generic class `PropertyCopier<Tin, TOut, TPropIn, TPropOut>` that copies a member using open property delegates and probably later a recursive call to the mass-copy function.
- The next step would be dynamically instantiating these generic types using reflection. For a simple pair of classes `TIn` and `TOut`, you should obtain a collection of `ICopyMember<TIn, TOut>`, one for each property.
- With this, you should be able to copy all properties from one object to the next. Just write a function that does this in a loop.
  Keep in mind that caching these property copiers and collections thereof would probably be a good idea. Keep them in a collection using the `Type` of the source and destination objects as key (or just that of the source object, if it's always copied to the same destination class).

Answer (score -1):

```
productList.ToArray();
```

What is wrong with List, btw?

Comment: I need to expose the class to PHP or asp which cannot accept List.